# Ears feel hot and eyes twitch after a cup of coffee

Tags: health

I have noticed that recently, my ears feel hot just immediately after a cup of coffee. And my eyes also starts to twitch some moments later.

Does this mean I should just quit taking coffee?

Comment: I believe this is something you should ask to an MD, not to a bunch of coffee fans. At first sight, you may have allergic reactions. However, the people on this site cannot come up with an (online) diagnosis.

Comment: You're right. I'll get my blood pressure checked to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Muscle twitching, especially in the eyelids, is a very common reaction to caffeine - I myself have that problem when I drink more than 3 cups of coffee in a day. Unless the twitching makes you uncomfortable and anxious there is no need to worry too much about it. If it does worry you, you should consider reducing your daily caffeine intake.

As for the hot ears, I get those when I drink something warm like a tea (or coffee) and when I eat something spicy. This also might be a harmless effect of the caffeine.

Nonetheless I would recommend you go see a doctor, or at least mention it the next time you visit one. What helped me with judging the effect of coffee on my body was to record my coffee intake and record any symptoms that might be caused by coffee. This, coupled with taking my temperature and blood pressure a few times throughout the day helped me to understand how my body reacts to certain beverages.